# Gradient fill for guage - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/vishalChakravarti/htex9qdy/2/

The angle of yellow gradient fill for the gauge chart in the above link is not following the chart enter code here.

Attaching the code for the same problem and jsfiddle as well. Thank you.

```
 yAxis: {
      stops: [
        [0.9, {
          linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            x2: 1,
            y1: 0,
            y2: 0
          },
          stops: [
            [0, '#00ff00'],
            [0.5, '#ffff00'],
            [1, '#ff0000']
          ]
        }]
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `linerarGradient` try `radialGradient: { cx: 0, cy: 1, r: 1.5 }`

You can try with different values here to see what works best for you.

```js
$(function() {

  var gaugeOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'solidgauge'
    },
    title: null,
    pane: {
      center: ['50%', '85%'],
      size: '140%',
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: {
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
      }
    },
    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      stops: [
        [0.9, {
          radialGradient: {
            cx: 0,
            cy: 1,
            r: 1.5
          },
          stops: [
            [0, '#00ff00'],
            [0.5, '#ffff00'],
            [1, '#ff0000']
          ]
        }]
      ],
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorTickInterval: null,
      tickPixelInterval: 400,
      tickWidth: 0,
      title: {
        y: -70
      },
      labels: {
        y: 16
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          y: 5,
          borderWidth: 0,
          useHTML: true
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // The speed gauge
  $('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 200,
    },

    series: [{
      data: [80],
    }]

  }));

  // Bring life to the dials
  setInterval(function() {
    // Speed
    var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts(),
      point,
      newVal,
      inc;

    if (chart) {

      /*       point = chart.series[0].points[0];
            inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
            newVal = point.y + inc;
            
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
              newVal = point.y - inc;
            }
            
            point.update(newVal); */
    }

  }, 500);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```

**API Reference**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors